# How do I redirect in .htaccess file without changing URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect several pages to a PHP page with GET variables. However, when I try to use an .htaccess file, it redirects but changes the URL. I don't want it to change the URL structure when redirecting. How would I do this?

For example, I want to redirect `/fly-snooze-cruise` to `http://example.com/package_listing.php?package-type=fly-snooze-cruise`

and `/fly-snooze-cruise/orlando-airport` to `http://example.com/package_listing.php?package-type=fly-snooze-cruise&airport=orlando-airport`

Here is my .htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^fly-snooze-cruise$ http://www.example.com/package_listing.php?package-type=fly-snooze-cruise [L]
RewriteRule ^fly-snooze-cruise/orlando-airport$ http://www.example.com/package_listing.php?package-type=fly-snooze-cruise&airport=orlando-airport [L]
RewriteRule ^fly-snooze-cruise/orlando-sanford-airport$ http://www.example.com/package_listing.php?package-type=fly-snooze-cruise&airport=orlando-sanford-airport [L]
RewriteRule ^fly-snooze-cruise/melbourne-airport$ http://www.example.com/package_listing.php?package-type=fly-snooze-cruise&airport=melbourne-airport [L]
RewriteRule ^snooze-park-cruise$ http://www.example.com/package_listing.php?package-type=snooze-park-cruise [L]
```

Comment: Remove the Http andHost name from your rewrite target if you dont wat url to change in brows.

Comment: @Starkeen Yes, that fixed it. Thanks.